# Tampermonkey, Click Button for x Times according to number of rows

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I have this table on a web site after runing a script and the number of rows is changes from time to time.

```html
<tbody id="appendHere">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sophHeader" colspan="7" width="â€œ550â€" style="text-align:center">Balanceador de recursos</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="25%" style="text-align:center">Origem</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="25%" style="text-align:center">Destino</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="5%" style="text-align:center">DistÃ¢ncia</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="10%" style="text-align:center">Madeira</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="10%" style="text-align:center">Argila</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="10%" style="text-align:center">Ferro</td>
                        <td class="sophHeader" width="10%">
                            <font size="1">Criado por Sophie 'Shinko to Kuma'</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
        <tr id="0" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=6662&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">004 - Tommy s2 (473|590) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=8931&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 14857 
Clay in WH: 5674
Iron in WH: 319
Warehouse capacity: 50675">Aldeia-bonus (474|589) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">1</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">11000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">16000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(6662,8931,11000,16000,0,0)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9261&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">005 - Tommy s2 (480|592) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=5204&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 59322 
Clay in WH: 11938
Iron in WH: 144136
Warehouse capacity: 400000">007 - Tommy s2 (478|591) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">5000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9261,5204,0,5000,0,1)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=1417&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">001 - Tommy s2 (477|588) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=4628&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 42731 
Clay in WH: 56624
Iron in WH: 21778
Warehouse capacity: 264611">006 - Tommy s2 (475|588) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">32000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(1417,4628,0,0,32000,2)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=5204&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">007 - Tommy s2 (478|591) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9261&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 127264 
Clay in WH: 133839
Iron in WH: 17195
Warehouse capacity: 264611">005 - Tommy s2 (480|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">2</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">15000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(5204,9261,0,0,15000,3)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=1417&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">001 - Tommy s2 (477|588) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=8931&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 14857 
Clay in WH: 5674
Iron in WH: 319
Warehouse capacity: 50675">Aldeia-bonus (474|589) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">3</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">42000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(1417,8931,0,0,42000,4)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=5204&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">007 - Tommy s2 (478|591) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=4628&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 42731 
Clay in WH: 56624
Iron in WH: 21778
Warehouse capacity: 264611">006 - Tommy s2 (475|588) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">4</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">8000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(5204,4628,0,0,8000,5)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=7953&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">002 - Tommy s2 (479|587) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=8931&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 14857 
Clay in WH: 5674
Iron in WH: 319
Warehouse capacity: 50675">Aldeia-bonus (474|589) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">5</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">16000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(7953,8931,16000,0,0,6)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="7" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9852&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">003 - Tommy s2 (473|594) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=8931&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 14857 
Clay in WH: 5674
Iron in WH: 319
Warehouse capacity: 50675">Aldeia-bonus (474|589) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">5</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">1000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">21000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9852,8931,1000,21000,0,7)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="8" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=5204&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">007 - Tommy s2 (478|591) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=6662&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 75890 
Clay in WH: 88803
Iron in WH: 4550
Warehouse capacity: 175047">004 - Tommy s2 (473|590) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">5</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">58000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(5204,6662,0,0,58000,8)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="9" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9261&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">005 - Tommy s2 (480|592) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=4628&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 42731 
Clay in WH: 56624
Iron in WH: 21778
Warehouse capacity: 264611">006 - Tommy s2 (475|588) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">6</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">4000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">15000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9261,4628,4000,15000,0,9)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="10" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9992&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">008 - Tommy s2 (471|596) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9261&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 127264 
Clay in WH: 133839
Iron in WH: 17195
Warehouse capacity: 264611">005 - Tommy s2 (480|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">10</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">30000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9992,9261,0,0,30000,10)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="11" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9992&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">008 - Tommy s2 (471|596) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11774&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 8327 
Clay in WH: 54473
Iron in WH: 6851
Warehouse capacity: 264611">BOOMBAYAH (465|604) K64</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">10</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">21000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9992,11774,0,0,21000,11)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="12" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9992&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">008 - Tommy s2 (471|596) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=7953&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 97669 
Clay in WH: 72685
Iron in WH: 16789
Warehouse capacity: 400000">002 - Tommy s2 (479|587) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">12</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">45000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9992,7953,0,0,45000,12)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="13" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11214&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Desert River (449|592) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11774&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 8327 
Clay in WH: 54473
Iron in WH: 6851
Warehouse capacity: 264611">BOOMBAYAH (465|604) K64</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">20</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">14000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(11214,11774,0,0,14000,13)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="14" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9992&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">008 - Tommy s2 (471|596) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11214&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 2484 
Clay in WH: 11949
Iron in WH: 78420
Warehouse capacity: 264611">Desert River (449|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">22</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">2000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9992,11214,2000,0,0,14)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="15" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9852&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">003 - Tommy s2 (473|594) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11214&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 2484 
Clay in WH: 11949
Iron in WH: 78420
Warehouse capacity: 264611">Desert River (449|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">24</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">36000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9852,11214,0,36000,0,15)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="16" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=18849&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Aldeia de bárbaros (451|627) K64 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11774&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 8327 
Clay in WH: 54473
Iron in WH: 6851
Warehouse capacity: 264611">BOOMBAYAH (465|604) K64</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">27</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">20000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(18849,11774,0,0,20000,16)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="17" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=7953&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">002 - Tommy s2 (479|587) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11214&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 2484 
Clay in WH: 11949
Iron in WH: 78420
Warehouse capacity: 264611">Desert River (449|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">30</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">17000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(7953,11214,17000,0,0,17)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="18" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9261&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">005 - Tommy s2 (480|592) K54 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=11214&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 2484 
Clay in WH: 11949
Iron in WH: 78420
Warehouse capacity: 264611">Desert River (449|592) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">31</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">42000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">24000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(9261,11214,42000,24000,0,18)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="19" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=18849&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Aldeia de bárbaros (451|627) K64 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=9852&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 104498 
Clay in WH: 242797
Iron in WH: 7146
Warehouse capacity: 400000">003 - Tommy s2 (473|594) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">40</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">17000<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(18849,9852,0,0,17000,19)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="20" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=18849&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Aldeia de bárbaros (451|627) K64 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=5204&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 59322 
Clay in WH: 11938
Iron in WH: 144136
Warehouse capacity: 400000">007 - Tommy s2 (478|591) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">45</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">4000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">1000<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(18849,5204,4000,1000,0,20)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="21" class="sophRowA" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=18849&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Aldeia de bárbaros (451|627) K64 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=4628&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 42731 
Clay in WH: 56624
Iron in WH: 21778
Warehouse capacity: 264611">006 - Tommy s2 (475|588) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">46</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">17000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(18849,4628,17000,0,0,21)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="22" class="sophRowB" height="40">
            <td><a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=18849&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink">Aldeia de bárbaros (451|627) K64 </a></td>
            <td> <a href="https://br109.tribalwars.com.br/game.php?village=1417&amp;screen=overview" class="sophLink" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wood in WH: 18460 
Clay in WH: 52015
Iron in WH: 147527
Warehouse capacity: 325337">001 - Tommy s2 (477|588) K54</a> </td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">47</td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">17000<span class="icon header wood"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header stone"> </span></td>
            <td width="50" style="text-align:center">0<span class="icon header iron"> </span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(18849,1417,17000,0,0,22)"></td>
        </tr></tbody>
```

What i need is to count the number of these buttons every time i run the page then click the intended button for x number of times that matches the same number of buttons like this found.

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btnSophie" id="building" tabindex="-1" value="Enviar recursos" onclick="sendResource(6662,8931,11000,16000,0,0)">
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Little Help ? :D

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share what you've tried so far. This page is invalid anyway since you can't have duplicate ids on a page. More details seem necessary.